# Changing model during training[tensorflow]

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, variable-initialization

I am creating a model in tensorflow with all layers having *relu* as the activation layer. However, when the batch size increases to 500, I want to change the model such that the second last layer to the output layer has *sigmoid* activation layer.

What I am confused about is that d I need to re-initialize all the variables since I am replacing the optimizer in the middle? Or do I keep the old variables?

Comment: You can use a conditional on the flow. But your architecture will not work as the weights were trained on another function so changing the activation function will basically reset the training process. Are you just tinkering around or you have solid theory background for this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. I think it depends on your datasets and models.

Yes: Perhaps, you can use weights (before batch size 500) as pre-trained like what Deep Belief Networks (with RBM) do.

No: Perhaps, these pre-trained weights hurt your model and may not better than other good initializers such as xavier initializer https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#xavier_initializer

I think it's worth try both options.

Comment: For starters what I was thinking of trying was copying the model and just updating the last activation link between the last hidden layer and the output layer. If so,  is there a way to keep the same model but update the activation link?

Comment: I haven't tried, but you can have two networks in one program and run (evaluate) one before 500 iterations, and run another one. I guess this may work.

Comment: If I use a different model, wouldn't that thrash all my trained variables? Which would mean that the model I trained (before batch size 500) would be useless. Right?

Comment: How about something like this:
L1 = XW1+b1
L2 = L2W2+b2
cost1 = costofL1(xxx, L1)
cost2 = costtoL2(xxx, L2)
trainop1 = optimize_cost1
trainop2 = optimize_cost2

I think you can run trainop1 first, then trainop2 later.